# #single_add_to_cart_button{ min-width: 100%!important; }

Tags: css, wordpress

Good day,

I am trying to make single_add_to_cart_button on my website be full **100% width** but I am really struggling to write what code and where to put it! I am really new to coding but I figured out that I need to add something like:

```
min-width: 100%!important;
```

I found the function-custom-css.php file which i think I need to modify. The css below is what i am staring at, it refers to single_add_to_cart_button twice but I haven't a clue where to put what code to make it work:

```
<?php if(get_theme_mod('color_checkout')) { ?>
    [data-icon-label]:after, .button#place_order,.button.checkout,.checkout-button,.single_add_to_cart_button.button{background-color: <?php echo get_theme_mod('color_checkout'); ?>!important }
<?php } ?>
```

Second Reference of single_add_to_cart_button:

```
<?php
    $color_secondary = get_theme_mod('color_secondary', Flatsome_Default::COLOR_SECONDARY);
    if( $color_secondary && $color_secondary !== Flatsome_Default::COLOR_SECONDARY ){ ?>
        /* Background Color */
        [data-icon-label]:after, .secondary.is-underline:hover,.secondary.is-outline:hover,.icon-label,.button.secondary:not(.is-outline),.button.alt:not(.is-outline), .badge-inner.on-sale, .button.checkout, .single_add_to_cart_button{ background-color:  <?php echo $color_secondary; ?>; }

        /* Color */
        .secondary.is-underline,.secondary.is-link, .secondary.is-outline,.stars a.active, .star-rating:before, .woocommerce-page .star-rating:before,.star-rating span:before, .color-secondary{color: <?php echo $color_secondary ;?>}
        /* Color !important */
        [data-text-color="secondary"]{color: <?php echo $color_secondary; ?>!important;}

        /* Border */
        .secondary.is-outline:hover{
        border-color:  <?php echo $color_secondary; ?>
        }
<?php } ?>
```

I am thinking about using the following in the custom css in the mean time but I need verification that it is correct:

```
#single_add_to_cart_button{
    min-width: 100%!important;
}
```

Here is what I found in developer tools:

```
element.style {
}

[data-icon-label]:after, .secondary.is-underline:hover, .secondary.is-outline:hover, .icon-label, .button.secondary:not(.is-outline), .button.alt:not(.is-outline), .badge-inner.on-sale, .button.checkout, .single_add_to_cart_button {
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
}
```

I would definitely prefer modify and save under the child theme than custom css.

Using wordpress, woocommerce, flatsome theme, any question please ask.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: I should note that I found the same single_add_to_cart_button reference in woocommerce.js but I fell off my chair when I opened the file.

Comment: Anyone able to help me with this? @sazzad-hossain was kind enough to suggest the correct code but I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

By default most boxes are displayed as inline-block objects, therefore do not get the container width. You can simple add `display: block;` and that should stretch the button for you the full width. Also it's best to double check if there's any other CSS classes that is interfering with your code.

Comment: thank you for the comment, could you tell me which file and where to put it in the code?

Comment: Add it to `#single_add_to_cart_button{...}`

Answer (score 0):

managed to get around this by using `.single_add_to_cart_button{min-width: 100%!important}`
in my css file, took a while but i got there!